# Regression on unbalanced two-way with interaction

Tags: regression, linear-model, experiment-design

I am developing my own algorithm to calculate it for me. I am interested in type III SS and using the overparametrized design matrix to estimate my parameters vector and then proceed to the cubic regression on the first factor. So using R, I have the data:

```
> dt
   X1 X2 X3
1   1  1 58
2   1  1 45
3   1  1 47
4   1  2 61
5   1  2 65
6   2  1 31
7   2  1 35
8   2  1 29
9   2  2 43
10  2  2 51
11  2  2 49
12  3  1 45
13  3  1 55
14  3  2 31
15  3  2 37
16  3  2 37
17  4  1 78
18  4  1 83
19  4  2 36
20  4  2 34
21  4  2 34
> dput(dt)
structure(list(X1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), X2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "2"), class = "factor"), X3 = structure(c(58, 
45, 47, 61, 65, 31, 35, 29, 43, 51, 49, 45, 55, 31, 37, 37, 78, 
83, 36, 34, 34), .Dim = c(21L, 1L))), .Names = c("X1", "X2", 
"X3"), row.names = c(NA, -21L), class = "data.frame")
```

The effects of $\mu$, $\alpha{_1}$, $\alpha{_2}$, $\alpha{_3}$, $\alpha{_4}$, $\beta{_1}$, $\beta{_2}$, $\alpha{_1}\beta{_1}$, $\alpha{_1}\beta{_2}$, $\alpha{_2}\beta{_1}$, $\alpha{_2}\beta{_2}$, $\alpha{_3}\beta{_1}$, $\alpha{_3}\beta{_2}$, $\alpha{_4}\beta{_1}$ and $\alpha{_4}\beta{_2}$ are estimated through
$$
\hat{b} = (X'X)^-X'y
$$

with X being

```
> X
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15]
 [1,]    1    1    0    0    0    1    0    1    0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 [2,]    1    1    0    0    0    1    0    1    0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 [3,]    1    1    0    0    0    1    0    1    0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 [4,]    1    1    0    0    0    0    1    0    1     0     0     0     0     0     0
 [5,]    1    1    0    0    0    0    1    0    1     0     0     0     0     0     0
 [6,]    1    0    1    0    0    1    0    0    0     1     0     0     0     0     0
 [7,]    1    0    1    0    0    1    0    0    0     1     0     0     0     0     0
 [8,]    1    0    1    0    0    1    0    0    0     1     0     0     0     0     0
 [9,]    1    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0     0     1     0     0     0     0
[10,]    1    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0     0     1     0     0     0     0
[11,]    1    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0     0     1     0     0     0     0
[12,]    1    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0     0     0     1     0     0     0
[13,]    1    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0     0     0     1     0     0     0
[14,]    1    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    0     0     0     0     1     0     0
[15,]    1    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    0     0     0     0     1     0     0
[16,]    1    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    0     0     0     0     1     0     0
[17,]    1    0    0    0    1    1    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     1     0
[18,]    1    0    0    0    1    1    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     1     0
[19,]    1    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     1
[20,]    1    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     1
[21,]    1    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     1
> dput(X)
structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1), .Dim = c(21L, 15L))
```

and ***y***

```
> y
      [,1]
 [1,]   58
 [2,]   45
 [3,]   47
 [4,]   61
 [5,]   65
 [6,]   31
 [7,]   35
 [8,]   29
 [9,]   43
[10,]   51
[11,]   49
[12,]   45
[13,]   55
[14,]   31
[15,]   37
[16,]   37
[17,]   78
[18,]   83
[19,]   36
[20,]   34
[21,]   34
> dput(y)
structure(c(58, 45, 47, 61, 65, 31, 35, 29, 43, 51, 49, 45, 55, 
31, 37, 37, 78, 83, 36, 34, 34), .Dim = c(21L, 1L))
```

yielding

```
> b <- ginv(crossprod(X)) %*% t(X) %*% y
> b
             [,1]
 [1,]  26.1666667
 [2,]  11.5000000
 [3,]   0.2777778
 [4,]   2.1666667
 [5,]  12.2222222
 [6,]  16.2666667
 [7,]   9.9000000
 [8,]  -3.9333333
 [9,]  15.4333333
[10,] -11.0444444
[11,]  11.3222222
[12,]   5.4000000
[13,]  -3.2333333
[14,]  25.8444444
[15,] -13.6222222
```

This $\hat{b}$ vector allows me to estimate the missing values on the data, leading to two possible regression scenarios: one with the original data that returns me the some coefficient values for the cubic regression, for example, and other with the three missing estimates that returns me different coefficients (which is the one I need).

Scenario 1:

```
> X
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]    1    1    1    1
 [2,]    1    1    1    1
 [3,]    1    1    1    1
 [4,]    1    1    1    1
 [5,]    1    1    1    1
 [6,]    1    2    4    8
 [7,]    1    2    4    8
 [8,]    1    2    4    8
 [9,]    1    2    4    8
[10,]    1    2    4    8
[11,]    1    2    4    8
[12,]    1    3    9   27
[13,]    1    3    9   27
[14,]    1    3    9   27
[15,]    1    3    9   27
[16,]    1    3    9   27
[17,]    1    4   16   64
[18,]    1    4   16   64
[19,]    1    4   16   64
[20,]    1    4   16   64
[21,]    1    4   16   64
> dput(X)
structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 16, 
16, 16, 16, 16, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 27, 27, 27, 
27, 27, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64), .Dim = c(21L, 4L))
> y
      [,1]
 [1,]   58
 [2,]   45
 [3,]   47
 [4,]   61
 [5,]   65
 [6,]   31
 [7,]   35
 [8,]   29
 [9,]   43
[10,]   51
[11,]   49
[12,]   45
[13,]   55
[14,]   31
[15,]   37
[16,]   37
[17,]   78
[18,]   83
[19,]   36
[20,]   34
[21,]   34
> dput(y)
structure(c(58, 45, 47, 61, 65, 31, 35, 29, 43, 51, 49, 45, 55, 
31, 37, 37, 78, 83, 36, 34, 34), .Dim = c(21L, 1L))
```

Scenario 2:

```
> X1
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]    1    1    1    1
 [2,]    1    1    1    1
 [3,]    1    1    1    1
 [4,]    1    1    1    1
 [5,]    1    1    1    1
 [6,]    1    1    1    1
 [7,]    1    2    4    8
 [8,]    1    2    4    8
 [9,]    1    2    4    8
[10,]    1    2    4    8
[11,]    1    2    4    8
[12,]    1    2    4    8
[13,]    1    3    9   27
[14,]    1    3    9   27
[15,]    1    3    9   27
[16,]    1    3    9   27
[17,]    1    3    9   27
[18,]    1    3    9   27
[19,]    1    4   16   64
[20,]    1    4   16   64
[21,]    1    4   16   64
[22,]    1    4   16   64
[23,]    1    4   16   64
[24,]    1    4   16   64
> dput(X1)
structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 
64), .Dim = c(24L, 4L))
> y1
      [,1]
 [1,] 58.0
 [2,] 45.0
 [3,] 47.0
 [4,] 61.0
 [5,] 65.0
 [6,] 63.0
 [7,] 31.0
 [8,] 35.0
 [9,] 29.0
[10,] 43.0
[11,] 51.0
[12,] 49.0
[13,] 45.0
[14,] 55.0
[15,] 50.0
[16,] 31.0
[17,] 37.0
[18,] 37.0
[19,] 78.0
[20,] 83.0
[21,] 80.5
[22,] 36.0
[23,] 34.0
[24,] 34.0
> dput(y1)
structure(c(58, 45, 47, 61, 65, 63, 31, 35, 29, 43, 51, 49, 45, 
55, 50, 31, 37, 37, 78, 83, 80.5, 36, 34, 34), .Dim = c(24L, 
1L))
```

Where Scenario 1 produces the coefficients:

```
> solve(crossprod(X)) %*% t(X) %*% y
           [,1]
[1,]  93.800000
[2,] -52.200000
[3,]  14.633333
[4,]  -1.033333
```

and Scenario 2 produces the different ones:

```
> solve(crossprod(X1)) %*% t(X1) %*% y1
           [,1]
[1,] 100.416667
[2,] -59.930556
[3,]  17.250000
[4,]  -1.236111
```

Finally leading to my question: is there an easier way to obtain the scenario 2 coefficients without having to rewrite the $X$ matrix and the $y$ vector (which is the estimation of the missing values)?
And, which scenario is correct? I mean, the recommended to fit the regression curve?